# Android 10 Create File Intent - How to get the reuslt URI?

Tags: android

I know how to let the user create a file in a self choosen external directory:

```
private static final int CREATE_FILE = 1;

private void createFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/json");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "test.json");

    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
}
```

How do i get the URI of the newly created File?
Or is there no way to do so unless with an additional file chooser intent?

Comment: Override `onActivityResult()`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#perform-operations).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, seems I just scrolled over it...